# How to get relationship/ assosiation in sequelizejs ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

By below reference I understood how map many to many with a relationship table

http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/associations#many-to-many

```
User = sequelize.define('User', { user_name : Sequelize.STRING})
Project = sequelize.define('Project', { project_name : Sequelize.STRING })
UserProjects = sequelize.define('UserProjects', {
    status: DataTypes.STRING
})

User.hasMany(Project, { through: UserProjects })
Project.hasMany(User, { through: UserProjects })
```

But how to query **Project** 's of a **User**

I Tried like

```
User.find({where:{id:1},include,[UserProjects]})
User.find({where:{id:1},include,[Projects]})
User.find({where:{id:1},include,[UserProjects]})
User.find({where:{id:1},include,[Projects]})
```

But i dont get results

Sequelize created table like below

```
users(id,name)
projects(id,project_name)
userprojects(id,UserId,ProjectId)
```

I tried https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Associations#hasmanytarget-options

```
User.find({where:{id:1}}).success(function(user){
    user.getProjects().success(function (projects) {
      var p1 = projects[0] // this works fine but 2 queries required. I expect in single find. without getProjects
      p1.userprojects.started // Is this project started yet?
    })
})
```

**How to get all the projects of a USER ??**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get all of the properties of the user in two different ways: using includes and getting the projects from a user instance.

Using includes the code you submitted above is almost right. This method will only make one query to the database using the JOIN operation. If you want all of the users with their corresponding projects, try:

```js
User.findAll({include: [Project]})
```

You can also get the projects directly from a user instance. This will take two queries to the database. The code for this looks like

```js
User.find(1).then(function(user) {
  user.getProjects().then(function(projects) {
    // do stuff with projects
  });
});
```

Does this work for you?